# Android method executing and results not on time

Tags: java, android

I have noticed that Android code is being executed by chunks, take this code for example

```
    actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            revealButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
            {
                View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, mainLinear, false);
                mainLinear.addView(child, 2);
            }
        }
    });
```

The Reveal button is not being visible untill the rest of the code is completed and *delivered* which in this case takes a second or two. So i tried to put it in chunks of code like:

```
   {
       revealButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
   {
       final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
       for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
       {
           View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, mainLinear, false);
           mainLinear.addView(child, 2);
       }
   }
```

I have also tried to make a two different static method trying to go too far to get this right which resulted in the same behaviour. The problem comes when i need to do some work but have to update the UI with instant results.

Comment: The problem I see here is that you're adding 50 `View` childs to the current view manually. I believe this would result in a way less efficient memory usage than if you were to do this with a structure for which the purpose **is** to show a lot of elements (e.g. a RecyclerView). Do all those 50 elements need to show up on the same screen region (with no scroll) ? If not, then you're better off  using a RecyclerView, that would only show the first elements, and consequently, update the UI faster (including your button).

Comment: This is just an example code of another complicated situation. The question is about the method result timing and not about how efficiency my code is ;|

Comment: The order in which the method is executed is sequential, as per Java. If you attach a debugger to your method and execute it step-by-step, you'll see that it is executed sequentially. However, this doesn't mean your UI thread will be updated with the exact same timing. When the UI doesn't "_follow_" your code, it often means the UI thread is busy. And that is an efficiency problem.

Comment: That result-at-the-end thingy is all over android, I can give another two examples of the ui thread being *blocked*.. Anyway most of the code being executed on the main thread so whats our options here...?

Comment: If the UI thread is blocked, it probably means you're doing something you shouldn't do. Have you tried moving the code of those _examples_ in an async task ?

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you're trying to do, exactly?

From the code it looks as if you're trying to render a list of views and show a reveal button to the user. Is that correct?

Either way, it seems to me the reason it's not updating immediately is because all the instructions are being executed on the same thread, which seems to be the Main Thread, so it will only update after it leaves the onClick block.

But I can't be sure on my answer. Could you give more details as to what you want to do, exactly? Is it to render a list of sorts or something else?

Comment: This is just an example code of another complicated situation. You are saying that the data is not delivered until the call ended. This doesn't make sense.. it's like the JVM clone the data, make the changes and then updates

Comment: Well, I can't really speak with great knowledge on how the JVM works, but google is pretty clear about how the UI thread. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads). Whether you're truly blocking it or whether it's performance as Arthur Attout mentioned in his comments, I'd take his suggestion and move any big work you do to another thread. Since it seems that you're rendering views, I'd recommend using one of the classes that Android provides, like a RecyclerView, it'll depend on your use case.